# xCode 9.3 breaks popover view width

Tags: ios, xcode9.3

Since I have updated to `XCode 9.3` all my popover views default to a width of `320`. If I go back to `XCode 9.2` everything is fine and the same popover views are shown with the regular width of `1024`.
This happens in my `main.storyboard` at every `ViewController` that is used as popover. If I try to overwrite the width, it jumps back to `320` again. The other views are showing normal width at `XCode 9.3`. It feels like the new `XCode` version reduces all popover views to an `iPhone` default width?

Does anyone has any idea, how to fix this? My app is for `iPad` only app (not universal).

Comment: You may want to show the code that calls the popover, plus the code that you use to set the width of the popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as follows, I had not set the content size box:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem here. Here's a demo in Xcode 9.3:
https://github.com/bvankuik/TestPopover

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in an iPad only app with a storyboard containing several UITableViewController based scenes with varying widths and heights. Before 9.3, these were created with widths matching the storyboard. Now they all arrive in viewDidAppear with size 375x667 if orientation is landscape and 320x480 if portrait.